basis in Hilbert spaces
Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $(x_n)$ a sequence with dense span. This is the standing assumption for the whole discussion.
Now consider the two possible additional assumptions:
(a) $\{ x_n: n \ge 1 \}$   is linearly independent
(b) the sequence $(x_n)$ is orthogonal.
Now (b) does imply that $(x_n)$ is a orthogonal basis, but (a) does not even imply that it is a Riesz basis (I read as a claim: not even a Schauder basis). A standard example seems the sequence of monomial functions in $L^2(-1,1)$ which spans the dense subspace of polynomials, and satisfies (a). To see that it is not Riesz we observe that a series $\sum_n \lambda_n x^n$ with $(\lambda_n)$ that is square summable yields a holomorphic function on the disc and not all $L^2$ functions are traces of holomorphic funtions. What is at first glance disturbing is that when we Gram-Schmidtify the monomials, we get an ONB of orthogonal polynomials, namely the Legendre polynomials (but rescaled a bit).
To my understanding that is a question of angles: the span ignores angles, and the size of coefficients,but for Hilbert-space-norms, angles, Pythagoras, etc  they are damn important.   Another example, in $\ell_2$ would be
$$
x_0 = (1,0,0,0,\ldots)
$$
and for $n\ge 1$ at
$$
x_n = (1-2^{-n}, 0, \ldots, 0, \sqrt{ 2^{-n+1}+4^{-n}}, 0, \ldots)
$$
that have, if I set it up correctly, all norm one. But taking scalar products $[x_n, x_m]$ yield values close to one, i.e. angles close to zero. Still, this sequence spans a dense subspace of $\ell_2$ (namely $c_{00}$) without being a Riesz  basis (indeed the map that sends the std basis vector $e_n$ to $x_n$ won't be an isomorphism). Orthogonality would correct that angle problem, and for example Gram-Schmidtifying my example sequence yields back the standard basis.
Therefore,a natural question is about "intermediate hypothesis". For example,
(a+)  assume (a) and additionally that $(x_n)_{n\ge N}$ is orthonormal for some $N\ge 1$ (i.e. we allow finitely many exceptions).    If it is only a point  about angles, finitely many "bad angles" should not deteriorate too much (since there is a minimum angle which is $>0$ by independence) and we should still get a Riesz basis. Is that right?

Actually, still no. The following is a counterexample: Let $H = l^2$, $x_n = e_{n - 1}$ for $n \geq 2$, and $x_1 = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e_n$ (or, really, any element of $l^2 \setminus c_{00}$ would do). Then $\{x_n\}$ is not a Riesz basis - indeed, $x_1 - \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n - 1} x_n = 0$.

If you’re thinking in terms of angles, what went wrong here is that $x_1$ has angle zero from the span of ${x_n: n \geq 2}$. If you have something like there exists $N \geq 1$ such that every nonzero vector in $\mathrm{span}{x_1, \cdots x_{N - 1}}$ has positive angle from $\mathrm{span}{x_n: n \geq N}$ (really, it just means $\mathrm{span}{x_1, \cdots x_{N - 1}} \cap \overline{\mathrm{span}}{x_n: n \geq N} = {0}$) in addition to ${x_n: n \geq N}$ being orthonormal, then you do get a Riesz basis.
